# Prevent digit entry in an input field

Tags: angular, validation

I have input fields and I wish it to be text and not digit. Example: name, first name

TypeScript

```js
this.etatCivilForm = formBuilder.group({
  idCivilite: ['', Validators.required],
  nomNaissance: ['', Validators.required],
  prenom: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[^(0-9)]')],
  nomUsage: [''],
```

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="prenom" tabindex="21" required autocomplete="off"
           placeholder="{{'etatCivil.prenom'|translate}}" maxlength="50">
    </mat-form-field>
    <p *ngIf="etatCivilForm.controls.prenom.value.valid">prenom n'est pas valide</p>
<mat-form-field>
```

Result: nothing is happening.

Comment: I want to just point out that `pattern` doesn't actually prevent digit entry if that is really what you want. It just checks if the value entered is valid or not. Also, please use only English.

Comment: is there a request to block numeric data entry?

Comment: Can you please add `Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[^(0-9)]')` in one array like `[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[^(0-9)]')]`

Comment: Kinjal, I already have that in array:  prenom: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[^(0-9)]')],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, `pattern` just checks that if the value matches the regex, if not, the field is considered invalid, but it doesn't block the user from entering values that aren't valid. You can add a `keypress` handler that checks the value entered, if ok, return the value, or block the entering with `event.preventDefault`. The following works with adding only letters and spaces. If you need something else, modify the regex to your needs. So try the following:

```html
<input formControlName="prenom" 
       (keypress)="checkValue($event)">
```

and the function:

```ts
checkValue(event) {
   return String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/) ? 
     event.CharCode : event.preventDefault();
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52mf4c?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add

```
onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode == 32))'
```

to input field.